# Categories from array sorted by parentID to url

Tags: php, arrays, tree, categories

I have this array:

```
$categories = array(
    array('id' => 1,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category A'),
    array('id' => 2,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category B'),
    array('id' => 3,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category C'),
    array('id' => 4,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category D'),
    array('id' => 5,  'parent' => 0, 'name' => 'Category E'),
    array('id' => 6,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory F'),
    array('id' => 7,  'parent' => 2, 'name' => 'Subcategory G'),
    array('id' => 8,  'parent' => 3, 'name' => 'Subcategory H'),
    array('id' => 9,  'parent' => 4, 'name' => 'Subcategory I'),
    array('id' => 10, 'parent' => 9, 'name' => 'Subcategory J'),
);
```

And as result i need this:
(simple for each category in $categories array need a link of full structure)

```
$result = array(
    '10' => 'Category D/Subcategory I/Subcategory J',
    '9' => 'Category D/Subcategory I',
    '8' => 'Category C/Subcategory H',
    '7' => 'Category B/Subcategory G',
    '6' => 'Category B/Subcategory F',
    '5' => 'Category E',
    '4' => 'Category D',
    '3' => 'Category C',
    '2' => 'Category B',
    '1' => 'Category A')
);
```

After that i can call link by $result[9] and get path "Category D/Subcategory I"
Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below should work for you.

Note: this function assumes that the array items are ordered so an item does not not depend on another item that is further down in the array (i.e. has been [topologically sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)).

```
function build_structure($arr) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        $value = ($item['parent'] == 0) ? $item['name'] :
                     $output[$item['parent']] . '/' . $item['name'];
        $output[$item['id']] = $value;
    }
    return $output;
}
```